What does Rev 17:10 "a short while" mean?
I understand that this passage can be interpreted many ways, but I am asking specifically for those who interpret the heads as kingdoms. If the 7th head is Roman, Caliphate, or another kingdom, how can it have lasted "a little while" since these lasted hundreds of years?
I know no Greek, but I was looking up the word "come", and it is aorist subjunctive active. Could it mean "after [the head ] has finished coming" "then at his [next] coming he will stay for a little while"? If not, how do commentators with the kingdom approach reconcile this?

they are also seven kings, five of whom have fallen, one is, the other has not yet come, and when he does come he must remain only a little while.


The Greek is quite straight-forward.  καὶ ὅταν ἔλθῃ ὀλίγον αὐτὸν δεῖ μεῖναι (Literally, and whenever he may come, a little he must to remain).  The subjunctive expresses potentiality.  That's not to say that he might not come.  The potentiality aligns with the sense of 'whenever'.  So, John is not expressing a specific time-frame.  The other thing of interest is that "a little (time) he" is fronted.  So, that information is expressed as more important in guiding the interpretation.  So, the when is not important, but the shortness is.

The only hint we have is the "one hour" in V12.

Answer
“A short while” in Revelation 17:10 means “a thousand, two hundred and sixty days” (Revelation 11:3) which is 3 ½ years only.
Explanation
According to Daniel 2:44, the fourth kingdom which is Roman Empire should continue until the second coming of Jesus Christ. But this will happen through a successive rising and falling of 7 kingdoms symbolized as 7 horns swayed by a little horn which had the “vision” (chezev) of a great “leader” (rab) according to Dan 7:20.
The little horn over the 7 horns is the same as the scarlet prostitute sitting on a beast with 7 heads in Revelation 17. This woman is controlling the 7 headed beast just as the little horn was the leader (rab) with a vision (chezev) over the 7 horns.
These 7 heads (or 7 horns) are sequential, one coming after the other:

“And the kings are seven. The five fell, and the one is, and the other
has not yet come. And when he does come, he must remain a little”
(Rev 17:10).

It is because of this sequential nature that the Roman Empire is mentioned as:

“The beast which you saw was, and is not, and is about to
come up out of the abyss, and goes to perdition” (verse 8).

Now just like the apostle John, the OP is “marveled, seeing her, with great marveling” (verse 6) and says: “If the 7th head is Roman, Caliphate, or another kingdom, how can it have lasted "a little while" since these lasted hundreds of years?”.
The angel tells us, ‘Why do you marvel?’ and tells the meaning in verse 7.
The original Roman Empire (“the beast”) is now history (“the beast was”). But it will survive (“about to come up”) through 7 consecutive kingdoms (“five fell, and the one is, and the other has not yet come”).
So, it is not the original Roman Empire that is going to last a little while but the seventh and last head (rising) of the erstwhile Empire that will last a little while (3 1/2 years).
How will it happen?
There are going to be 10 kings in this seventh and last kingdom that will come up from Europe (the seat of the Roman Empire beast). But these ten leaders will hand over their power unanimously to an end time Great Dictator, the real Beast; someone like an Adolph Hitler with tremendous modern and latest war making capabilities!

“And the ten horns you saw are ten kings who have not yet received a
kingdom, but will receive authority as kings one hour with the beast.
These have one mind, and their power and authority they shall give
up to the beast” (Rev 17:12-13).

Why will they last only a little while?
Because by that time Jesus Christ will come in glory with His saints angels:

“These (the Great Dictator and ten kings) will make war with the Lamb,
and the Lamb will overcome them, because He is Lord of lords and
King of kings, and the ones with Him are the called and elect and
faithful ones” (verse 14).

Jesus Christ also says why they will last only a little while:

“For there will be great affliction, such as has not happened from
the beginning of the world until now, no, nor ever will be. And except
those days were shortened, not any flesh would be saved. But on account of the elect, those days will be shortened” (Mat 24:21-22).

So, it is God who made the time shorter as otherwise the Great Dictator would use his nuclear weapons annihilating all life from earth. Hence Jesus said, “not any flesh would be saved”!
How the Great Dictator will appear?
He will come first as a peace loving great leader. As all dictators do, he will make war “to end all wars”. He will establish his peacekeeping force with the headquarters built between Mediterranean Sea and Jerusalem. But things will turn ugly shortly:

“He will even set up his huge royal tents between the sea and the
mountain on which the Temple stands. But he will die, with no one
there to help him” (Dan 11:45).

(Verse 40 clearly says this is “the end time” and the immediately following Dan 12:1-2 talks about the resurrection of the saints).
Conclusion
So, the original Roman Empire “was, and is not but will come” in seven successive kingdoms and will go into perdition. The seventh and the last will be terrible causing the Great Tribulation known as Jacob’s Trouble and will last “a little while” which is equal to three and a half years.

I think shortness implies the direct path from A to B.
so it could be 1000 yrs, 10 days or whateever.
The point is that their are no other distractions interferrig with the event.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Rev. 17:10 And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space.   1. Egypt
2. Assyria
3. Babylon
4. Medo-Persia
5. Greece
6. Rome
7. Antichrist
8. Chris Jesus returns.
Keeping in mind when John is writing this (during Roman rule), the first five kingdoms have fallen, Rome is, and  Antichrist empire is yet to come.  The Antichrist will not have complete power until the defeat of the two witnesses at the midpoint of tribulation, leaving only a 3 1/2 year span for his rule before the second coming of Christ at the seventh trumpet.

The short answer is: about a little more than 2,300 evenings and mornings. The book of Daniel 8:14, why I will explain a little more below.
A response with justification:
Any tangle unwinds from the end, so I'll start with the eighth king. In the book of Revelation 17:8, 11-14. The eighth king is described.
Its characteristics:

At first he was, then he was gone, then he will come out of the abyss and then go to perdition. The reason for his death is indicated by a mortal wound from the sword Revelation 13:14.
People who are not inscribed in the book of life will be surprised at his healing after a mortal wound from the sword and seeing his power, they will worship him.
This king is from among the seven, that is, he will take the basis from some one king from the previous seven.
The Ten horns (all the other kingdoms on earth) will join the eighth king and transfer their power and authority to him.
They will wage war with the Lamb, that is, a war with God's people on earth is equated with a war against Jehovah and Jesus. They will succeed in this for 3.5 years (Revelation 13:7) but at the end of the allotted time, he will be killed.
He will be given time to rule for one symbolic hour.
Revelation 13:7 adds:
The eighth king will be given power over the whole earth.

To enrich your knowledge about the eighth king, please read the scripture in Revelation 11:7; 13:1-10; in the book of Daniel chapters 7, 8, 12
It is noteworthy that Revelation 13:11-18 describes another beast that gives power to the eighth king. This beast appears before the 8th king, therefore it is the 7th king. As we can see from the above verses 7, the king is doing everything possible for people to follow the 8th king. He both deception and miracles and directly forces people to put the sign of the beast, just as the king monitors the restrictions of those people who will not put this sign. People who do not put a sign will not be allowed to buy or sell, that is, people who do not put this sign of the beast will in fact be doomed to perish, they will be killed. It turns out that the 7th king will be the ancestor of the 8th king, his hands will do all the things on earth, and he will be a little in the shade. Since the 8th king is the king in plain sight and sets the tone for all the other ten kings (the number 10 symbolically reflects earthly fullness and means that all kings on earth will follow him Revelation 13:7) then it is he who is the collective image of the entire political system of Satan in recent times, in Revelation 13:12. 8 The king is even called the first beast (apparently described in Revelation 13:1, 2, which is the political system of Satan in recent times before armageddon). This symbiosis of the 7 and 8 kings is so closely intertwined that the prophet Daniel in chapter 2 describes it with feet without separating, consisting of iron and clay. The metal in the statue symbolizes the rule of Satan, the head is golden, and the shins (rule of the Roman Empire) They're already made of iron. Apparently, in the time of Babylon, Satan could control, with the help of wisdom, the people on earth, but in the time of the Roman Empire, only by brute force. At the time of the 7th and 8th kings, his influence had already weakened so much that there was already a rule from people. Satan, who broke off relations with God for the sake of power, who wanted to be His equal, is undoubtedly enraged. Therefore, Satan establishes such orders: "if you are not under my rule, you will be destroyed." That is why when Satan is accused by God, then in one of the points there are these words Isaiah 14:20 "for you have destroyed your land, killed your people." This also explains why there are so many wars before the end of this system of things. It is significant that the 8th king, like the 7th, should take the basis from the Roman Empire, since iron symbolizes its rule. This basis is described in the Bible in the book of Acts, when the Apostle Paul was captured and flogged, and when they found out that he was a Roman citizen, they were afraid. From this passage it can be seen that the Roman citizen had rights and all the others were people of the 2nd class. Who is hiding under the name of the 8th king? If you remember about the 3rd Reich, which translates as 3 Rome, remember about their flags and standards, about the awards in the form of the Iron cross, about their ideology "the peoples of northern Europe, including England and Italy, are Aryans — the race of the masters all the rest, either slaves or dead", remember that they considered themselves an exceptional people and on the buckles of their soldiers they wrote "God is with us", to remember that they received a mortal wound from a sword in 1945. they ceased to exist and people thought that this rule would be over forever (that's why they would be surprised when this rule was reanimated), and they themselves said that they were the heirs of Rome. Who is the 7th king then? In Revelation 13:11, this king has two horns, indicating two centers of power. He looks righteous but speaks or acts like a dragon or Satan. Who now has two centers of power, aspires to world domination, supports Nazism in Ukraine? President Zelensky applauds former SS members in the Canadian Parliament. I guess that those living within the influence of the 7th tsar did not even see this video, we had it well on TV channels. I was horrified to learn that in the London Town Hall since the 17th century there have been stuffed two giants Gog and Maggog, they are considered the guardians of London and a procession is held in their honor every year. I did not read something in the Bible that Satan openly told people somewhere that "I am your ruler" and you must obey me, he always hid under some kind of mask and this is his next one. In my understanding, the 7th tsar is an Anglo-American power. Moreover, England is put in the first place not by chance, she is the head of this union, America is the power and strength of this union, but England is the head. Anglo-America has been living like the Roman Empire for a long time, everyone else just has to do its will. It's just that their allies (vassals) have different ratings, someone is closer to them and has more privileges, someone is further away, and someone is generally subject to destruction. To complete the picture of the 7 and 8 kings, you need to open the book of Daniel chapters 7, 8, 12. Among the many additions, there is interesting information: Daniel 7:8. There is no doubt that we are talking about the 8th king, because it is this horn that will attack the people of Jehovah, the attack will last 3.5 times and after it will be destroyed, these key data coincide with the information from Revelation said about the beast whose mortal wound has healed. So, going back to the book of Daniel 7:8, that 3 horns should be pulled out before the 8th king. It remains only to impose this Biblical knowledge on the reality that exists today, and understand how the current confrontation will end. What will happen next when these three horns are pulled out in front of the 8th king? Next, the words of 1 Thessalonians 5 will be fulfilled:3. After the fall of the 3 kingdoms before the 8th king, expectations of peace and security will prevail in the world, but the world will enter a period of destruction of the evil system built by Satan. Who will be the first to be destroyed in Satan's system?  Revelation 11:1, 2 answers this question. Why is someone measuring something? In order to check the conformity of the measured object with the standard and, if necessary, correct the flaw. In this case, the temple of God, the altar and the worshippers in it are measured first, and the courtyard of the temple is not yet measured. What is hidden behind the concept: the temple of God, the altar, and the worshippers in it? All religions are their works and their people. Since there is only one truth for Jehovah, after this test, one true religion will remain, all the others fall under the description of the "whore of Babylon" the destruction of the "whore of Babylon" will happen rapidly (Revelation 18:10). But the cleaning of the sanctuary will not be completed, there is still the outer courtyard of the temple, which will be given to the pagans for 42 months. The full time for cleaning the sanctuary is indicated in Daniel 8:14 "2300 evenings and mornings". Thus, it turns out that the 7th tsar will receive power for a little more than 2,300 days. That is, first he pulls out 3 kings in front of the 8th king, people have a feeling of peace and security and at this moment immediately or with a very short delay, the 7th king attacks all religions of the world a period of 2300 days begins, the last 1260 days the 8th king must come out of the abyss. To summarize: the phrase "he will not be long" mentioned in Revelation 17:10 refers to the 7th king and is equal to a little more than 2,300 days; The phrase "for one hour" Revelation 17:12 refers to the 8th king who will be supported by all the kingdoms on earth and this symbolic hour is equal to 1260 days.

Welcome to Hermeneutics! Our site's primary language uses English, so we don't include translations in other languages inside a post unless it is a small quote needed to explain. And, we try to keep answers very concise, which can be difficult since we all struggle with that (read more here). Can you edit this and make it shorter, especially cutting down point 7 and removing the translated part?

Thanks Jesse. Your advice helps me make my answers better. I looked at what could be shortened and left a lot anyway. Unfortunately, it doesn't work out any shorter. Next time I will try to find a less succinct question and then my answer will be shorter. Thanks again to Jesse.
